# custom linked list iteration

Tags: java, iteration

I have a java web app that has to save a bunch of items as user add to cart then display each item the user added on a jsp page. I have a custom made linked list called "Cart" that doesn't use any library/API(whatever you call it) just for practicing purpose. Cart includes a bunch of Node and Product is the E element of each Node.

if Node is a public outer class, then I can iterate using "Node current" outside of the class (i.e. main, other pages). but if I put Node as inline class which most people do, then I can't do that. Is there any way to iterate through the list without moving the Node outside?

Comment: If I'm adding things to the list, why do I *care* what's storing the data in the list itself?  Why should you expose your `Node` class?  (Hint:  **don't!**)

Comment: I guess you want to implement `Iterable<Product>` in your linked list and create a inner class that implements `Iterator<Product>` to retrieve the elements?

Comment: To Makoto, I need to get the item. Display it on the check out page. Something that looks like the cart page in amazon. Quantity, Product name, product price, and a check out button or continue shopping.

Comment: Can you an example code fabian? just small example with simple link list like string or int

Comment: Don't know if I'm using the right one but just followed an example on custom on custom Iterator, but MyIterator it = cart.iterator() is required to use it. So it's the same problem as calling Node current = cart.getHead(); Both Node and MyIterator are inline classes.